# How to keep data in Object

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a table or tables in sqlServer. I want to take data from database and keep this table's data into objects like class, but I dont want to keep this data into dataset.

- What are those ways to keep data into objects taking data from database?
- How can I pass data into object but not in dataset or datatable?

Comment: Did you ever considered the ORM ?

Answer (score 1):

[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is what you should be looking for.

For .Net framework you can look into

- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)
- [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)
- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: Dapper is not really an ORM, it certainly does not belong in that list.

Answer (score 1):

ORM is the solution as mentioned above.....

Better use entity frame work that is good for this purpose.......it will creates entity classes with all your tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** as it is suggested in the comment, some [type of **ORM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object relational mapping) will do that magic for you.

**Good references** on this topic are the followings:

- [4 Benefits of Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)](http://blogs.learnnowonline.com/blog/bid/210553/4-Benefits-of-Object-Relational-Mapping-ORM)
- [ORM mapping data to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12106802/1437962)
- [DataObjects.Net - ORM Framework for RAD - Introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85533/DataObjects-Net-ORM-Framework-for-RAD-Introduction)

**Edit:** To choose the **right ORM** for your problem, look at this Wikipedia article

- [**List of object-relational mapping software**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).